# Joining two tables with same id bringing duplicates

Tags: sql

Sorry probably i am not explaining it correctly..

so i am updating my question ..

below is the scenario... I have to join many similar table like this and there are similar table with single row which are fine to me and they have different key1... If i specifically add Key1=key1 then i will drop here .. not sure what to do ..

```
create  TABLE ##ZZSP00(
    empl    BIGINT,
    key1     INT,
    sal decimal
)

INSERT INTO ##ZZSP00 ( empl, key1 ,sal ) VALUES  ( 1, 2,10)
INSERT INTO ##ZZSP00 ( empl, key1 ,sal ) VALUES  ( 1,3, 20)     
INSERT INTO ##ZZSP00 ( empl, key1 ,sal ) VALUES  ( 1, 4,30)    

create  TABLE ##ZZSP01(
    empl    BIGINT, 
    key1     INT,
    descr   VARCHAR(10)
)


 INSERT INTO ##ZZSP01 ( empl, key1 ,descr ) VALUES  ( 1, 2,'apple')
 INSERT INTO ##ZZSP01 ( empl, key1 ,descr ) VALUES  ( 1,3, 'orange')     
 INSERT INTO ##ZZSP01 ( empl, key1 ,descr ) VALUES  ( 1,4, 'kiwi')
```

**Wrong results**

-- Kind of mini Cartesian is happening here

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ##ZZSP00 a 
JOIN ##ZZSP01 b
ON a.empl=b.empl
```

**right results**

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ##ZZSP00 a 
JOIN ##ZZSP01 b
ON a.empl=b.empl AND a.key1=b.key1
```

Comment: Hint: Left Join

Comment: What is the query you are actually using?

Comment: six rows --- which is wrong
select a.key,a.name,b.key,b.name,c.key,c.name
 from table1 a
join table2 b
on a.key=b.key
join table3 c
on a.key=c.key


3 rows -- whic is right 
select a.key,a.name,b.key,b.name,c.key,c.name
 from table1 a
join table2 b
on a.key=b.key
join table3 c
on a.key=c.key 
where b.key2=c.key2

Comment: Still you need is not clear we need a logic to exclude the table 3 from the cartesian multiplication of the join

Comment: try this `SELECT a.key,a.name,b.key,b.name,c.key,c.name 
FROM table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
WHERE a.key=c.key
AND b.key=b.key
GROUP BY b.key2, c.key2;`

Comment: So did you slove your problem? Because your Update question doesn't match your origin question.
@raj

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 
    GROUP BY id
to group all the data with same id's

Comment: could you please share sql

Comment: try this. 

select 
t1.key,
t1.key2,
t1.name,
t2.name,
t3.name
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
left join table3 t3 on t1.key = t3.key
group by t1.key;

OR 

select 
t1.key,
t1.key2,
t1.name,
t2.name,
t3.name
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
left join table3 t3 on t1.key = t3.key
where t1.key = 123;

Answer (score 0):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` ON `table1` and `table2` by `[key]`

`INNER JOIN` ON `table2` and `table3` by `[key2]`

```
SELECT t1.[Key],t1.key2,t2.key2,t3.key2,t1.name,t2.name,t3.name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.[key] = t2.[key]
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.[key2] = t3.[key2]
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1f234/1*

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select 
t1.key,
t1.key2,
t1.name,
t2.name,
t3.name
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
left join table3 t3 on t1.key = t3.key
group by t1.key
```

OR

```
select 
t1.key,
t1.key2,
t1.name,
t2.name,
t3.name
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
left join table3 t3 on t1.key = t3.key
where t1.key = '123'
group by t1.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry probably i am not explaining it correctly..below is the scenario... I have to join many similar table like this and there are similar table with single row which are fine to me and they have different key1... If i specifically add Key1=key1 then i will drop here .. not sure what to do ..

```
create  TABLE ##ZZSP00(
    empl    BIGINT,
    key1     INT,
    sal decimal
)

INSERT INTO ##ZZSP00 ( empl, key1 ,sal ) VALUES  ( 1, 2,10)
INSERT INTO ##ZZSP00 ( empl, key1 ,sal ) VALUES  ( 1,3, 20)     
INSERT INTO ##ZZSP00 ( empl, key1 ,sal ) VALUES  ( 1, 4,30)    

create  TABLE ##ZZSP01(
    empl    BIGINT, 
    key1     INT,
    descr   VARCHAR(10)
)


 INSERT INTO ##ZZSP01 ( empl, key1 ,descr ) VALUES  ( 1, 2,'apple')
 INSERT INTO ##ZZSP01 ( empl, key1 ,descr ) VALUES  ( 1,3, 'orange')     
 INSERT INTO ##ZZSP01 ( empl, key1 ,descr ) VALUES  ( 1,4, 'kiwi')
```

**Wrong results**

-- Kind of mini Cartesian is happening here

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ##ZZSP00 a 
JOIN ##ZZSP01 b
ON a.empl=b.empl
```

**right results**

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ##ZZSP00 a 
JOIN ##ZZSP01 b
ON a.empl=b.empl AND a.key1=b.key1
```